# Setting up custom principal to impersonate Sql Server user

Tags: sql-server, authentication, single-sign-on, wif, claims-based-identity

What do I need to do in order to use custom principal (Preferrably a claim based one) to impersonate a Sql Server user.

```
        var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                /* What do I need in here? */
            };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            claims, "Basic", "UserName", ClaimTypes.Role);

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
```

In the end I want SQL Server to trust my application layer, and the principal/role that it defines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not support that.